# Wait for page to load using webdriverjs with mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

In the following code example, clicking on the anchor with id `openPage` should open a new page. The test only succeeds, when using a short delay `sleep(1000)` as `getCurrentUrl` does not seem to wait until the page is loaded.

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('openPage'));
element.click();

driver.sleep(1000);

var promise = driver.getCurrentUrl();
promise.then(function (url) {
   assert.strictEqual(url, 'page title');
});
```

What would be the proper (async) way to code this without using a delay ?

Comment: This might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520812/how-do-i-detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how I would use a JavaScript page ready event with WebDriverJS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This great article](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html) answers my question to perfection and resulted in the following helper function I'm now using to wait for a page to be loaded:

```
function waitForPageLoad (driver, timeout) {
    var oldHtmlElement;

    // check the arguments
    if (typeof timeout === 'undefined') {
        timeout = 5000;
    } else {
        if (typeof timeout !== 'number' || timeout <= 0) {
            throw new TypeError('The argument timeout must be a integer > 0');
        }
    }

    // get the html tag on the old page
    oldHtmlElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('html'));

    // wait until the function returns true or the timeout expires
    driver.wait(function () {
        // get the html tag on the (eventually already) new page
        var newHtmlElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.tagName('html')),
            newHtmlElementId = newHtmlElement.getId(),
            oldHtmlElementId = oldHtmlElement.getId();

        // compare the id of the html tag on the page with the one we just got
        //  and if it's no longer the same one, we must be on the new page.
        return oldHtmlElementId !== newHtmlElementId;
    }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: you can mark your answer as being correct if you think it is correct