# How to detect page load without javascript?

Tags: html, dom, pageload

I am creating a page to work on low-end devices. Where JS support may not be available or very poor.
So I want to hit an  tag on page load for Tracking purpose.

Please help.

Comment: please try this one:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520812/how-do-i-detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520812/how-do-i-detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
window.whenloaded = function(fn) {
  if (window.onload) {
    var old = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
      old();
      fn();
    }
  } else {
    window.onload = fn;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520812/how-do-i-detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded)

Comment: Thanks. but this is with JS and i want a solution without JS