# How to know the browser page whether is loading in Vue.js project?

Tags: javascript, browser

How to know the browser page whether is loading in Vue.js project?

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

in browser, such as in Chrome, if we open a page, if the networking is not finish, there will have a circle animation.

but in our development, how can we get this status?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey In my project, I use a third part lib, which will download something about it, there will give a fetch time. but I am not sure when it can download finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **simple Javascript**

```
if (document.readyState == "completed") {
    alert("Your page is loaded");
}
```

**Return Value**:   A String, representing the status of the current document.

One of five values:

- uninitialized - Has not started loading yet
- loading - Is loading
- loaded - Has been loaded
- interactive - Has loaded enough and the user can interact with it
- complete - Fully loaded

For more details visit [W3Schools - document.readystate](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp).

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Really good answer. OP should probably take a look at it since it's a very usefull alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is the javascript/HTML `onLoad()` event.
It's called when a page has been loaded, as an HTML tag you can add a  function 
call which will be executed once the page is loaded and same goes for Javascript where you can create an eventListener to call a function following the same event.

Here is an helpfull link: [OnLoad W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Window.onload() method detect when a page is loaded. may this  can be helpful

[How do I detect when a web page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520812/how-do-i-detect-when-a-web-page-is-loaded)