# React detect page has fully loaded including network requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to detect if a page has completely loaded, including network requests.

I'm currently using `useLayoutEffect` which is great for detecting if the DOM has completely loaded, but I still have network fetches occuring on the page. I want to add an event listener to all images on the page, but can only do this once EVERYTHING has finished loading.

I do of course having loading states for individual component that exist on the page, but I need a global way of detecting if all components has finished loading, or that the page itself has finished loading.

Any suggestions appreciated.

I did also try to use the document.readyState but this appears to just behave the same way useLayoutEffect does in that it only detects DOM elements loaded.

```
document.readyState === 'complete'
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: another post with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57729504/is-there-a-way-to-tell-when-your-react-app-page-is-done-loading-the-page-asset

Comment: @FabioRibeirodeCarvalho yes I did see that one before too, and as mentioned in my post I already tried that method too :)